# Lifting a map to the total space of a circle bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, fibration

Let $\pi:P \to M $ be a smooth circle bundle, so $S^1$ is the fibre, $f:N \to M$ a smooth map. I would like to know what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $f$ to lift to a map $g:N \to P$ covering $f$.

There are related questions reading which I *think* the answer is that $f$ lifts if and only if $f^*:H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})\to H^2(N,\mathbb{Z})$ is the zero map. However my understanding of algebraic topology is very basic and I cannot quite follow the arguments presented, so I would like for someone to confirm or  correct what I wrote. Incidentally, advice for the most accessible introduction to obstruction theory you know of would be appreciated.

In fact I am interested in a related but slightly different question: with $\pi:P\to M$ as above when does a diffeomorphism $f:M\to M$ lifts to a map $h:P\to P$? If the above criterium is correct $f$ lifts if and only if $\pi^*: H^2(M) \to H^2(P)$ is the zero map. Can anything be said about when that happens given that $P$ is a circle bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need obstruction theory for that: $f$ lift to $g$ if and only if $[v]=f^*([u])=0$ where $u\in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is the Euler class of $P\rightarrow M$. To see that:

Consider the pullback $f':P'\rightarrow N$ of $P\rightarrow M$. It is classified by $[v]$.  $[v]=0$, if and only if $P'\rightarrow N$ is trivial, This is equivalent to $P'$ is isomorphic to $N\times S^1$ which induces a section $g':N\rightarrow P'$ that can be composed with $P'\rightarrow P$ (the projection of the pullback). On the other hand, if the map $g$ is a lift of $f$, $g$ defines a section of the pullback of $P\rightarrow M$ by $f$, which is thus trivial since it is a principal bundle.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues I'd like to address.  First, is a distinction that must be made between a circle bundle and a principal circle bundle.  What you described is a circle bundle: a fiber bundle where the fiber happens to be diffeomorphic to $S^1$.  In contrast, a principal circle bundle is a circle bundle for which there is a consistent choice of free,transitive $S^1$ action itself.

There are circle bundles which are not principal; the simplest example is probably the Klein bottle as an $S^1$ bundle over $S^1$.

A principal bundle over a base $B$ gives rise to a distinguished element $e$ (called the Euler class) which lives in $H^2(B;\mathbb{Z})$.  The condition on lifting is *not* that $f^\ast$ be the zero-map, but rather, that $f^\ast(e) = 0$.  Tsemo gave a fine proof that this condition is sufficient; the necessity follows from the fact that the kernel of the map $H^2(B;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^2(P;\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $e$.

But I want to stress that the argument involving the Euler class does not work for non-principal bundles (because the don't have an Euler class).  And, indeed, the result is false in this case.

To see this, consider the unit tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}P^2$, $T^1\mathbb{R}P^2$.  This is diffeomorphic to the lens space $L(4,1)$, as argued in Proposition 4.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06844.pdf).

Now, consider the natural projection $\pi:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$.  Because $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion, while $H^2(S^2;\mathbb{Z})$ is not, the induced map on $H^2$ must be the trivial map.

On the other hand, $\pi$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_2(S^2)\rightarrow \pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)$.  Because lens spaces are covered by $S^3$, they have trivial $\pi_2$, so the map $\pi:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ cannot lift to a map into $L(4,1)$.

Comment: $T^1\mathbb{R}P^2$ is a circle bundle associated to a principal $O(2)$-bundle (i.e. the frame bundle of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ given a suitable Riemannian metric). Any circle bundle associated to a principal $SO(2)$-bundle is necessarily principal (basically because $SO(2)\cong S^1$). Thus if $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ is an *orientable* (smooth) circle bundle, then $f:N\rightarrow M$ lifts to $P$ if and only if its action on $H^2(-;\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial. Jason, do you know what to say in the non-orientable case?

Comment: @Tyrone:  Unfortunately, no, I don't.  If anything, that question is more up your alley than mine ;-)

Comment: Dear Jason, thank you very much for your answer and for the clarifications. Do you have a quick argument/reference for the fact that the kernel of the map $\pi^*: H^2(B)\to H^2(P)$is generated by $e$? Also Tsemo argument also covers the necessary part and seems fine to me, did you provide another one because you have some issues with it or just because the more the merrier?

Comment: @GFR:  The argument for the kernel of $\pi^\ast$ I'm thinking of comes from the Gysin sequence.  Once can also view this as coming from the Serre Spectral Sequence, or by looking at what happens in the universal principal $S^1$ bundle $S^\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^\infty$.  As far as Tsemo's argument also covering the necessity, I just hastily read his answer; I agree it also covers the necessity.  But, sure, the more the merrier - we'll go with that ;-).